# find the orthogonal family of the family of curves for : ${(x^2+y^2)}^2=cy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know the algorithm needed to find the orthogonal family for a family of curves. However in this one I somehow can't succeed in solving the ODE.
I would really appreciate the help 
(side note:) the orthogonal ODE that I got is: $y'=\frac{-4y^2}{x^2+y^2-4xy}$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your differential equation can be expressed in the following way :

$$(x^2+y^2-4xy)dy=-4y^2dx$$

which belongs to the category of **homogeneous differential equations** with a standard way to solve them (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation).

Up to you now...

(I fear there is no simple solution to the resulting differential equation)

---

Edit : A quite different approach.

Split the initial equation into a family of cartesian equations, by expressing $x$ as a function of $y$ :

$$x=\underbrace{\pm\sqrt{-y^2 \pm \sqrt{cy}}}_{g(y)}$$

then use the classical method for orthogonal curves knowing their cartesian equations ($dx/dy=-1/g'(y)$)

Comment: See the edit I just wrote.